# I am not able to view Add-In ribbon in Outlook (2013)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have created Outlook Add-In using Visual Studio 2013. Added simple ribbon control to add menu. But when I run the application, I am not able to view the add-in although it is activated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any UI errors?

By default, if an VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors

1. Start the application.
2. Click the File tab.
3. Click Options.
4. In the categories pane, click Advanced.
5. In the details pane, select Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors, and then click OK. For Outlook, the Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors checkbox is located in the Developer section of the details pane. For other applications, the checkbox is located in the General section of the details pane.

Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Also Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in when you try to debug it, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in. See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Do you try to customize the Fluent UI using the Ribbon designer or just by using a Ribbon XML markup?

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)